# How to apply a function to increasing subsets of a time series Pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, apply

I have a Pandas data frame containing time series data. I would like to compute some statistics over an increasing number of data points. Simply put, I would like to re-compute the statistics as new data points come in. I can do this for a sorted data frame `df` via a for loop like this

```
 results = [myStatFun(df.Feature[0:i].tolist()) for i in range(5,len(df))]
```

where `myStatFun` returns a multidimensional vector.

This gets the job done, but seems sub-optimal. Can I use the `apply` function in some way? I don't really care if the end results is a data frame or array.

Comment: Please show `myStatFun` to help further.

Comment: @Parfait why does that matter? myStatFun takes a list of row features from the data frame and computes statistics over them and returns a list or an np array. For simplicity let say it computes the ML estimate of the Gamma distributions parameters into an array. I am interested in the general case where myStatFun can be any function acting on a part of the data frame.

Comment: There may be room to vectorize your function instead of looping. I do not see any issue with original line. If code works and in your specified time, this question may be better put on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).